# Git Install in Home Directory as User: Errors?

Tags: git, unix, compilation, makefile, bsd

I am trying to install git within my home directory on a unix server where I have a shell account as a user but do not have root privileges. I am following the instructions in on these sources:

[How to install Git on a shared host](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/)

[git/scm book](http://book.git-scm.com/2_installing_git.html)

and the INSTALL file instructions within the git source directory but keep getting an endless list of mostly repeats of this error message:

```
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 1510: Need an operator
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 1511: warning: duplicate script for target "ifdef" ignored
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 278: warning: using previous script for "ifdef" defined here
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 1512: warning: duplicate script for target "ifdef" ignored
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 278: warning: using previous script for "ifdef" defined here
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 1513: Need an operator
make: "~/haziz/opt/bin/src/git/Makefile" line 1514: Need an operator
```

Just to clarify this is within my home directory not on the system where I do not have root privileges.

Any ideas or suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Tried running the command as gmake per Greg Hewgill's suggestion.

now the error messages are:

```
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:285: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:65: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:286: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_attr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:66: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_attr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:288: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_once_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:71: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_once_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:289: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_mutexattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:68: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_mutexattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:290: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_mutex_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:67: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_mutex_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:291: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_condattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:70: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_condattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:292: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_cond_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:69: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_cond_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:293: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_rwlockattr_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:74: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_rwlockattr_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:294: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_rwlock_t'
/usr/include/pthread_types.h:73: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_rwlock_t' was here
/usr/pkg/include/pthread.h:357: error: conflicting types for 'pthread_kill'
/usr/include/signal.h:69: error: previous declaration of 'pthread_kill' was here
```

Comment: What is the command line exactly that you are using? Is it `make && make install`? The reason I ask is that I'm surprised to to see the "~" and your full path in those error messages.

Comment: I did edit the messages a little, partly for brevity. It actually gives the full path, pwd style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this type of error is caused by using the wrong `make`. You're probably using a BSD-style `make`, while Git requires a GNU-style `make`. A GNU-style make may already be installed as `gmake` on your system, otherwise you'll have to go find and build one of those, too.

Comment: Actually the server I refer to is in fact running netbsd. Any suggestions?

Comment: (1) try `gmake`. (2) If that doesn't work, get [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/s/make/) and build that first.